# pyttsx3作成したmp3ファイルがhtmlで読み込めない

Tags: python, html, macos, mp3

掲題の通りですpyttsx3で作成したmp3ファイルがhtmlファイルのaudioタグに埋め込んでも「再生できません」と表示されます。
パスが正しいことは確認済みなのですが、同じようなトラブルに見合われた方はいますでしょうか？
OSはmacOSで音声の変換にはffmpegを使用しています。

Comment: 問題の発生するhtmlやその環境(サーバー種類/版数と設置場所・使用ブラウザ・読み込み方法)などの、他の人が問題を再現/検証するために必要な色々な情報を追記してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: HTML からではなく、一般的なメディアプレイヤーでファイルが再生可能な事は確認済みですか？ (ファイルそのものが正しくない状態になっている可能性もあります)

Answer (score 0):

こちらの環境は以下の通りです。

- Python   3.9.5
- pyttsx3  2.90

以下のコードで MP3 ファイルを作成して、

```py
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.setProperty('rate', 100)
engine.setProperty('volume', 1.0)

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
voice = list(filter(lambda v: v.name == 'Japanese', voices))[0]
engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

engine.save_to_file('スタックオーバーフロー', 'output.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

HTML5 の audio タグに埋め込みます。一応は再生できているので、参考にしてみてください。

```js
const speech = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,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';

const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.src = speech;
```

```html
<audio id='audio' controls></audio>
<p>音声を再生するには audio タグをサポートしたブラウザが必要です。</p>
```